# HTTP Post and Get to download CSV file - Error

Tags: http, post

**The page keeps getting back to login. I verified that the credentials are passed to the request. No luck. Please help. I need this done in the next day or two. Anything I am missing here?** I have gone this forum the past two days but just could not figure it. Sorry if this is duplicate.

```
Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse

Dim myURL1 As String

Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse

Dim myURL1 As String

Dim myURL2 As String

Dim myURL3 As String

Dim cookieJar As New CookieContainer

Dim myReq As Net.HttpWebRequest

Dim strngData as String

' Network Credentials

Dim cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential ("myLogin", "myPassword", ".genscape.com")

' Login Page URL

myURL1 = https://apps.genscape.com/NAPowerRT/login.jsp
'URL to scrape data

myURL2 = https://apps.genscape.com/NAPowerRT/planthistory.do?
plantid=9976&numDays=1&format=0/genscape-03_26_12-03_27_12-9708.csv

' Action URL in Form with method = POST

myURL3 = "https://apps.genscape.com/NAPowerRT/j_spring_security_check"

myReq = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(myURL1)

myCache.GetCredential(myURL1, 0, "http")

myReq.Credentials = cred



'Get Cookies

myURL1 = "https://apps.genscape.com/NAPowerRT/login.jsp"

myReq = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(myURL1)

myReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"

myReq.Method = "GET"

myReq.CookieContainer = cookieJar

myReq.KeepAlive = True

response = myReq.GetResponse

For Each tempCookie As Net.Cookie In response.Cookies

   cookieJar.Add(tempCookie)

Next

myReq.GetResponse.Close()

'Sent POST data

myReq = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(myURL3)

myReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"

myReq.Method = "Post"

myReq.AllowAutoRedirect = True

myReq.ContentType = "text/html"

myReq.Credentials = cred

myReq.CookieContainer = cookieJar


'Send request to URL that has data with cookies from previous GETs
' ----- The below results in login page instead of page where the csv is located

myReq = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(myURL2)

myReq.Credentials = cred

myReq.Method = "get"

myReq.ContentType = "text/csv"

myReq.Accept = "text/html"

myReq.AllowAutoRedirect = True

myReq.KeepAlive = True

myReq.CookieContainer = cookieJar

'Get the data from the page

response = myReq.GetResponse

Dim streamreponse As Stream = response.GetResponseStream

Dim stream As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

strngData = stream.ReadToEnd()

response.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NetworkCredential` class is for HTTP authentication.  The app you are trying to log into uses form-based authentication.

Instead of using HTTP auth, simply build a urlencoded POST request with the login and password.  There is also a hidden field in the login form that may be significant.

It also looks like the company you are trying to get data from offers a proper data feed product.  It is likely a better option.